# Read GET parameter along with submiting form

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I have link `../index.php?id=1`. When user comes to this page, he can extend time of his published article by the number of days he entered. I need to get id of this article from **GET** parameter, but when I submit form link becomes just `../index.php` without any get parameters. Is there any way to submit form without losing get parameter, or something like this. Form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

Enter number of days:
<input type="text" name="days">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: `<form action="index.php?id=10" method="post">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST method can have GET parameters. They are not mutually exclusive.

```
<form action="index.php?id=1" method="post">
```

For your specific case:

```
<form action="index.php?id=<?= $_GET['id']?>" method="post">
```

Of course, `id` in the GET parameter can be accessed from `$_GET`.

```
<?php
/**
  * Submit action target page (index.php in this case)
  */

$id = $_GET['id']; // GET params
$days = $_POST['days']; // POST params
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the method of the form to get and you'll get the days variable by `$_GET['days']`. Otherwise, you can get the number of days using `$_POST['days']`.

To keep the get parameter, you can add a hidden field to the form during the form generation.

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">

Enter number of days:
<input type="text" name="days">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

However, do note that it won't be safe since the user would be able to modify it during form submission.